# DJI Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample Save YUV To JPEG

Tags: android, jpeg, yuv, dji-sdk

I am trying to convert the YUV frames to JPEG for Mavic 2 Pro. This is done using the `newSaveYuvDataToJPEG420P` or `newSaveYuvDataToJPEG` functions in [repo](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample/blob/master/android-videostreamdecodingsample/app/src/main/java/com/dji/videostreamdecodingsample/MainActivity.java).
However, I observe that the incoming data is not complete, `yuvFrame.length < width * height` the data size is not equal to the product of width and height. So the data is not processed.
**What may be the reason for this discrepancy?**

Comment: Have you done this, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple YUV formats

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YUV_420_888

Mostly likely the format used is [YUV_420_888](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420p_(and_Y%E2%80%B2V12_or_YV12)_to_RGB888_conversion) as this is more common for cameras which representation, 8 bits for Y and 4 bits for UV (interleaved).

Thus `yuvFrame.length = width * height * 12 bits` or (6 bytes per 4 pixels)

The frame will have all 3 colour channels in it's length so it's length would never equal width times height in bytes.

Where as YUV444 is 3 bytes per pixel

So that test in the code is logically wrong as would not detect some incomplete YUV frames. The correct test would be `yuvFrame.length < width * height * 1.5f`

The only reason I can think of why it is failing this incorrect test is that the image format is not YUV, a lot of cameras can output jpeg natively as a jpg frame could fail this test.

Note that you can use the Android [YuvImage class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage) to convert YUV images to jpeg